# prevent ng-include loading until ng-if ="bool" bool set true;

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angular-ng-if

**my objective:** i want to prevent carousel download images  until caurosel button is clicked

**version with ng-if**  images not loading in carousel.

```
  <button ng-click=" visSlide=false" > thumbnails </button >   
  <button ng-click=" visSlide=true"  > carousel</button >

  <div ng-if="!visSlide" ng-include src="'_thumbnails.html'"> </div>

  <div ng-if="visSlide" > 
      <div ng-include src="'_carousel.html'"> </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**____________ ____________ ____________ ____________**

**with ng-show** loads everthing and keeps them hidden if ng-show="false".

( saw it in firebug net tab )

```
<div ng-show="!visSlide" ng-include src="'_thumbnails.html'"> </div>
<div ng-show="visSlide" ng-include src="'_carousel.html'"> </div>
```

**__________________________________**

**carousel.html**  works when i use ng-show in the parent.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="5000"  >
    <!--slides bootsrap carousel-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
        <div ng-repeat="item in imglinks"  class="item {{ $index==0 ? '  active':''}}" >  
            <img ng-src="{{ img_pre + item.img_org }}" style="margin:0  auto; max-height:500px" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li ng-repeat="item in imglinks" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{$index}}" 
        class="{{ $index==0 ? 'active' : '' }}" ></li> 
    </ol>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What code is inside _carousel.html?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but there is the problem in placing both ng-if and ng-include on same element.

So,
Change this

```
<div ng-if="!visSlide" ng-include src="'_thumbnails.html'"> </div>
```

to

```
<div ng-if="!visSlide" > 
   <div ng-include src="'_thumbnails.html'">

    </div>
</div>
```

[Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3307)

Comment: thanks but .in post i already did it like what you said .i researched  alot but couldnt find a solution.